# Can I prevent Outlook 365 from removing recipients from attached email file?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

There's a process at work where I build out email messages for other people programmatically, then save each email as an `.msg` file, then email each file to the appropriate person. Each of those people opens the `.msg` file in Outlook on their desktop and then sends it from their Outlook accounts.

The problem with emailing them the `.msg` files is that Outlook always empties the content of the recipient fields (TO, CC, BCC). We don't want this to happen, because that content is one of the reasons I'm building the emails programmatically. So I end up having to send the files to people over Teams.

Is there any way to prevent Outlook from emptying the contents of the TO/CC/BCC fields in `.msg` files when sending them as email attachments?

Comment: You could perhaps zip up the files.

Comment: I could try doing that, I would just rather avoid littering users' machines with zip files, and forcing them to do the extra step of extracting the emails, if possible. I was just hoping there was some Outlook app setting I could ask users to change, or some 365 setting I could request that our Org changes

Answer (score 0):

Are you using other clients to send attachments? As far as I know, many clients do not support the .msg format. It is recommended that you send it in the Outlook client.
https://www.howtogeek.com/695636/how-to-forward-an-email-as-an-attachment-in-microsoft-outlook/

Comment: I'm using Outlook to send the attachments, and all the recipients are using Outlook to receive, open, and send the attachments. The issue I'm having is that Outlook is clearing out the CC, TO, and BCC fields when the users open the attachments.  Those fields remain intact if I send the attachments via Teams, so I know it's either the Outlook clients (or some 365 server) that's clearing out the fields.